# What's the difference between property class and property decorator

Tags: python, cython

I have seen a code which used this way for defining a property

```
property sockets:
    def __get__(self):
        cdef list sockets = []
```

does it have any difference with declaring it with a decorator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__get__` and et al way of defining property functions is legacy syntax and deprecated in favour of the `@property` decorators - [per docs](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#properties):

> There is also a special (deprecated) legacy syntax for defining properties in an extension class:

```
cdef class Spam:

    property cheese:
```

The code generated by Cython is functionally equivalent and can be seen by examining the C files but the syntax is legacy, deprecated and may be removed in future Cython versions.